# Таблица истинности в С++

Tags: c++

Нужно написать программу, которая бы составляла таблицу истинности введенной ДНФ, например `(A & B) | (B & C)`, и для этого выражения вывести таблицу истинности.

Comment: нужно — пишите.

Comment: Подсказываю алгоритм. Обращаетесь за решением к самому затюканному отличнику на вашем потоке. Обещаете взамен конспект или шпаргалку по какой-нибудь гуманитарной дисциплине.

Comment: @VladD лучше оплатить в твердой валюте. Кому нужны эти гуманитарные дисциплины? :)

Answer (score 5):

1. Разобрать выражение. Подойдет алгоритм сортировочной станции.
2. По итогам разбора узнать количество параметров
3. По итогам разбора научиться вычислять значение формулы на векторе параметров X
4. Генерируя все возможные комбинации для вектора X (их будет 2^n, где n - размерность вектора), заполнить таблицу истинности.

Если вы ждете, что я напишу вам код - не дождетесь.